# SharePoint 2007 outgoing email to users not in Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can someone please direct me to a tutorial about this topic?
I can't seem to find one.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- http://sptraining.sharepointsite.net/default.aspx
- http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-tutorials/
- http://sharepoint-videos.com/

Comment: outgoing settings has been configured in Central Admin, but it doesn't send to external users.